# What Layout XML should I use for the about page of an android app?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface

I can't seem to find any good resource or guidelines for making the about section of an app I'm making.

Using a `Preference` xml seems not a good idea to me *as there are no preferences to make*. I need to just display textual information. The only interaction required is for showing those Open-source licenses, TOS, the version, etc.

See this about page of the Google app:

[image]

I have no clue what is a good (may not be the best) way to implement like in the above linked image.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: AFAIK there isn't really anything special about your "about" activity versus any other activity in your Android app.  Just pick a layout and design which _you_ think works and would fit well with your expected users.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to implement something like this your best bet would be using a `RecyclerView` with an [`DividerItemDecoration`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/DividerItemDecoration) (for the grey line). The item of your RecyclerView simply needs to support a Title and a Subtitle. The Subtitles visibility should be gone by default, so your item (which should be `wrap_content`) is not unnecessarily stretched. This way you can reproduce the screen of the image you have linked

Comment: ListView has been there since API v1. Why RecyclerView when all the items are visible and nothing to recycle? Also ListView has the dividers visible by default.

Answer (score -2):

If your about page is a static one use constraint layout as parent and textviews as children. But if it is a dynamic list use recyclerview for better performance.